# Would force due to linear acceleration be equal to centripetal force regarding SpinLaunch

Tags: acceleration, centripetal-force, space

SpinLaunch uses a large rotating arm to spin a projectile at high RPM before releasing the projectile with enough velocity to nearly reach earth orbit. I have a question comparing G-forces in SpinLaunch to a linear cannon's G-forces.

Could a long-barrel cannon accelerate a projectile to the same velocity as the current SpinLaunch design using the same G-forces?  What are some of the parameter trade-offs which would impart to the projectile the same velocity with the same maximum G force using these two concepts?

I recently watched this documentary on SpinLaunch:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeoh-EE9TXU

**Edit:** Apparently the problem seems to be the 3rd derivative (Jerk) more than acceleration (2nd derivative).

[image]

Comment: it's an interesting question, but a simple calculation. Have you considered doing it yourself?

Comment: Just thoughts... When held and spinning the side load on the rocket, depending on how it's held, could cause the rocket to fold (the whole support, preventing folding, might have to be released with the rocket simultaneously). I also visualize, for each rotation of the support arm the rocket is also turning one revolution in the plane of swing. When the rocket is released, wouldn't the rocket tend to maintain its angular momentum at release? If so, the air friction after exit could tear the rocket apart (let alone what might happen in the tube). The in-rush of air when port opens will be huge.

Comment: @JimClark the video documentary addresses your question in detail, and I recommend it (linked in OP).